# Why are recent badges shown on the main page?

Tags: discussion, badges, homepage

The only useful function which I can see of this feature that it teaches (shows new users different badges), but I would say the "Badges" menu does a way better job of that.

So why are recently awarded badges shown on the main page? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are they shown... where?

Comment: @animuson, on the main page, right sidecolumn, bottom.

Comment: @animuson: sorry forgot to mention where. I update the title of question

Comment: You should add some tag to your question to make it easier to find it by research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, when I first entered StackOverflow as a new user, I was pleased to see that it was showing gratitude to his user. And the badge section was, to me one, of the section showing gratitude. When you see those golden badge for famous answers or stuff like that with the user name it's pretty nice and you want to write great answer to get there.

Also, it makes you discover some badge that may be unknown to you and when you click on it you can discover how to earn it. That way you learn more about the site, and the way it works.

Another point is that, when you see badge from great answers/questions and click on it you can  go to the question and see the question/answer itself to see what make it a great answer/question and thus helping you making better answer/question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's just eye-candy motivation to show new users that badges are being awarded constantly, and they can go get some.